# What are the exclamation and question marks/points called in variants of English?

Tags: american-english, terminology, punctuation, british-english, transatlantic-differences

As regards `!`, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclamation_mark) reads

> The exclamation mark, !, or exclamation point (American English)

but it doesn't use a corresponding wording for `?`:

> The question mark ? (also known as interrogation point,

So my question is whether `!` and `?` are both called *mark* in British English and *point* in American English.

Comment: Wikipedia does use [_interrogation point_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_mark).

Comment: Sure, but it doesn't make any reference to whether that's the America, British, or xyz variant.

Comment: Well, if you look up "interrogation point" in the dictionaries, you will see it listed as American.

Comment: I’ve never heard “point” in America for either ! or ?   They’re both marks.

Comment: @Jim: That's what I thought at first. But compare [AmE usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=exclamation+mark%3Aeng_us_2019%2Cexclamation+point%3Aeng_us_2019&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) (mostly "point"), and [BrE usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=exclamation+mark%3Aeng_gb_2019%2Cexclamation+point%3Aeng_gb_2019&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) (mostly "mark"). That was an unexpected US/UK usage split, to me.

Comment: Adding to this (apparently opinion-based) thread: while this older AmE speaker has heard exclamation *point* more often than *mark*, I've never heard question *point*, ever

Comment: Just to confuse things it used to be common in BrE to hear the interrogation mark being referred to as "a query". I haven't heard it in a while, though.

Comment: [What are A and B called.]

Comment: “What”, not “how”! English differs from other Germanic and Romance languages in this respect.

Answer (score 1):

As Ngram shows, [American English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=exclamation+mark%2Cexclamation+point%2Cquestion+mark%2Cquestion+point&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3) typically uses "exclamation point" but "question mark." [British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=exclamation+mark%2Cexclamation+point%2Cquestion+mark%2Cquestion+point&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3), by contrast, uses "mark" in both cases.

Answer (score -1):

Someone said they never heard of exclamation point in America. That's funny because I was born here and have lived here for 60 years and it's always been called an exclamation point, all through school and college.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).